# mysql2sqlite.sh script is not working as required

Tags: database, github, gsub

I am using mysql2sqlite.sh from script [Github](https://gist.github.com/esperlu/943776#file-mysql2sqlite-sh)  to change my mysql database to sqlite. But the problem i am getting is that in my table the data **'E-001'** gets changed to **'E?001'**.

I have no idea how to modify the script to get the required result. Please help me.

the script is

```
#!/bin/sh

# Converts a mysqldump file into a Sqlite 3 compatible file. It also extracts the MySQL `KEY xxxxx` from the
# CREATE block and create them in separate commands _after_ all the INSERTs.

# Awk is choosen because it's fast and portable. You can use gawk, original awk or even the lightning fast mawk.
# The mysqldump file is traversed only once.

# Usage: $ ./mysql2sqlite mysqldump-opts db-name | sqlite3 database.sqlite
# Example: $ ./mysql2sqlite --no-data -u root -pMySecretPassWord myDbase | sqlite3 database.sqlite

# Thanks to and @artemyk and @gkuenning for their nice tweaks.

mysqldump --compatible=ansi --skip-extended-insert --compact "$@" | \

awk '

BEGIN {
FS=",$"
print "PRAGMA synchronous = OFF;"
print "PRAGMA journal_mode = MEMORY;"
print "BEGIN TRANSACTION;"
}

# CREATE TRIGGER statements have funny commenting. Remember we are in trigger.
/^\/\*.*CREATE.*TRIGGER/ {
gsub( /^.*TRIGGER/, "CREATE TRIGGER" )
print
inTrigger = 1
next
}

# The end of CREATE TRIGGER has a stray comment terminator
/END \*\/;;/ { gsub( /\*\//, "" ); print; inTrigger = 0; next }

# The rest of triggers just get passed through
inTrigger != 0 { print; next }

# Skip other comments
/^\/\*/ { next }

# Print all `INSERT` lines. The single quotes are protected by another single quote.
/INSERT/ {
gsub( /\\\047/, "\047\047" )
gsub(/\\n/, "\n")
gsub(/\\r/, "\r")
gsub(/\\"/, "\"")
gsub(/\\\\/, "\\")
gsub(/\\\032/, "\032")
print
next
}

# Print the `CREATE` line as is and capture the table name.
/^CREATE/ {
print
if ( match( $0, /\"[^\"]+/ ) ) tableName = substr( $0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1 )
}

# Replace `FULLTEXT KEY` or any other `XXXXX KEY` except PRIMARY by `KEY`
/^ [^"]+KEY/ && !/^ PRIMARY KEY/ { gsub( /.+KEY/, " KEY" ) }

# Get rid of field lengths in KEY lines
/ KEY/ { gsub(/\([0-9]+\)/, "") }

# Print all fields definition lines except the `KEY` lines.
/^ / && !/^( KEY|\);)/ {
gsub( /AUTO_INCREMENT|auto_increment/, "" )
gsub( /(CHARACTER SET|character set) [^ ]+ /, "" )
gsub( /DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP|default current_timestamp on update current_timestamp/, "" )
gsub( /(COLLATE|collate) [^ ]+ /, "" )
gsub(/(ENUM|enum)[^)]+\)/, "text ")
gsub(/(SET|set)\([^)]+\)/, "text ")
gsub(/UNSIGNED|unsigned/, "")
if (prev) print prev ","
prev = $1
}

# `KEY` lines are extracted from the `CREATE` block and stored in array for later print
# in a separate `CREATE KEY` command. The index name is prefixed by the table name to
# avoid a sqlite error for duplicate index name.
/^( KEY|\);)/ {
if (prev) print prev
prev=""
if ($0 == ");"){
print
} else {
if ( match( $0, /\"[^"]+/ ) ) indexName = substr( $0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1 )
if ( match( $0, /\([^()]+/ ) ) indexKey = substr( $0, RSTART+1, RLENGTH-1 )
key[tableName]=key[tableName] "CREATE INDEX \"" tableName "_" indexName "\" ON \"" tableName "\" (" indexKey ");\n"
}
}

# Print all `KEY` creation lines.
END {
for (table in key) printf key[table]
print "END TRANSACTION;"
}
'
exit 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't give a guaranteed solution, but here's a simple technique I've been using successfully to handle similar issues (See "Notes", below).  I've been wrestling with this script the last few days, and figure this is worth sharing in case there are others who need to tweak it but are stymied by the awk learning curve.

The basic idea is to have the script output to a text file, edit the file, *then* import into sqlite (More detailed instructions below).

You might have to experiment a bit, but at least you won't have to learn awk (though I've been trying and it's pretty fun...).

**HOW TO**

- Run the script, **exporting to a file** (instead of passing directly
  to sqlite3):

  `./mysql2sqlite -u root -pMySecretPassWord myDbase > sqliteimport.sql`
- Use your preferred text editing technique to clean up whatever mess
  you've run into.  For example, search/replace in sublimetext.  (See the last note, below, for a tip.)
- Import the cleaned up script into sqlite:

  `sqlite3 database.sqlite < sqliteimport.sql`

**NOTES:**

- I suspect what you're dealing with is an encoding problem -- that '-' represents a character that isn't recognized by, or means something different to, either your shell, the script (awk), or your sqlite database. Depending on your situation, you may not be able to finesse the problem (see the next note).
- Be forewarned that this is most likely only going to work if the offending characters are embedded in *text* data (not just *as* text, but actual *text* content stored in a text *field*).  If they're in a machine name (foreign key field, entity id, e.g.), binary data stored as text, or text data stored in a binary field (blob, eg), be careful.  You could try it, but don't get your hopes up, and even if it *seems* to work be sure to test the heck out of it.
- If in fact that '-' represents some unusual character, you probably won't be able to just type a hyphen into the 'search' field of your search/replace tool.  Copy it from the source data (eg., open the file, highlight and copy to clipboard) then paste into the tool.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

To convert mysql to sqlite3 you can use Navicom Premium.

[image]